# Reference problem in Visual Studio after built CMake projects

Tags: c++, visual-studio, cmake

When i use `target_link_libraries` in *CMakeLists.txt* file that link my library with my executable test project, i built cmake projects and in Visual Studio i found the created reference.
[Visual Studio library reference to executable](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CYpaB.png)

I tried to compile my projects and it seems all ok, but when i open my executable output path, i can't see referenced .dll and i investigated which problem occurs. In library reference i check if *Copy local* option was checked and in the mid time i see that and exception was occured in the *Path* property:
 `The Microsoft.VisualStudio.ProjectSystem.References.UnresolvedBuildDependencyProject Reference" reference could not be resolved.`

[Visual Studio executable reference properties](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Jo7vt.png)

Anyone knows the solution for this problem?

**lensmeter_calculation_test CMakeLists.txt (executable)**

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.15)

set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 17)
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD_REQUIRED ON)
set(CMAKE_POSITION_INDEPENDENT_CODE ON)

if(NOT DEFINED LENSMETRER_COPY_FILES)
    set(LENSMETER_COPY_FILES FALSE CACHE BOOL "Specify if you want to copy sources and headers to build directory and refer to these" FORCE)
endif()

file(GLOB_RECURSE LENSMETER_CALCULATION_TEST_HEADER_FILES "include/*.hpp")
file(GLOB_RECURSE LENSMETER_CALCULATION_TEST_SOURCE_FILES "src/*.cpp")
file(GLOB_RECURSE LENSMETER_CALCULATION_TEST_RESOURCE_FILES "resources/*.*")

if(${LENSMETER_COPY_FILES})
    foreach(SOURCE_FILE ${LENSMETER_CALCULATION_TEST_SOURCE_FILES}) 
        string(REPLACE ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR} ${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR} DESTINATION_FILE ${SOURCE_FILE})
        get_filename_component(DESTINATION_FOLDER ${DESTINATION_FILE} DIRECTORY)    
        list(APPEND LENSMETER_CALCULATION_TEST_SOURCE_FOLDERS ${DESTINATION_FOLDER})
        list(APPEND LENSMETER_CALCULATION_TEST_BINARY_FILES ${DESTINATION_FILE})
        file(COPY ${SOURCE_FILE} DESTINATION ${DESTINATION_FOLDER})
    endforeach()
else()
    foreach(SOURCE_FILE ${LENSMETER_CALCULATION_TEST_SOURCE_FILES}) 
        get_filename_component(DESTINATION_FOLDER ${SOURCE_FILE} DIRECTORY) 
        list(APPEND LENSMETER_CALCULATION_TEST_SOURCE_FOLDERS ${DESTINATION_FOLDER})                
    endforeach()

    list(APPEND LENSMETER_CALCULATION_TEST_BINARY_FILES ${LENSMETER_CALCULATION_TEST_SOURCE_FILES})
endif()

if(${LENSMETER_COPY_FILES})
    foreach(SOURCE_FILE ${LENSMETER_CALCULATION_TEST_HEADER_FILES}) 
        string(REPLACE ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR} ${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR} DESTINATION_FILE ${SOURCE_FILE})
        get_filename_component(DESTINATION_FOLDER ${DESTINATION_FILE} DIRECTORY)
        list(APPEND LENSMETER_CALCULATION_TEST_HEADER_FOLDERS ${DESTINATION_FOLDER})
        list(APPEND LENSMETER_CALCULATION_TEST_BINARY_FILES ${DESTINATION_FILE})
        file(COPY ${SOURCE_FILE} DESTINATION ${DESTINATION_FOLDER})
    endforeach()
else()
    foreach(SOURCE_FILE ${LENSMETER_CALCULATION_TEST_HEADER_FILES}) 
        get_filename_component(DESTINATION_FOLDER ${SOURCE_FILE} DIRECTORY) 
        list(APPEND LENSMETER_CALCULATION_TEST_HEADER_FOLDERS ${DESTINATION_FOLDER})                
    endforeach()

    list(APPEND LENSMETER_CALCULATION_TEST_BINARY_FILES ${LENSMETER_CALCULATION_TEST_HEADER_FILES})
endif()

if(${LENSMETER_COPY_FILES})
    foreach(SOURCE_FILE ${LENSMETER_CALCULATION_TEST_RESOURCE_FILES})   
        string(REPLACE ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR} ${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR} DESTINATION_FILE ${SOURCE_FILE})
        get_filename_component(DESTINATION_FOLDER ${DESTINATION_FILE} DIRECTORY)
        list(APPEND LENSMETER_CALCULATION_TEST_RESOURCE_FOLDERS ${DESTINATION_FOLDER})
        list(APPEND LENSMETER_CALCULATION_TEST_BINARY_FILES ${DESTINATION_FILE})
        file(COPY ${SOURCE_FILE} DESTINATION ${DESTINATION_FOLDER})
    endforeach()
else()
    foreach(SOURCE_FILE ${LENSMETER_CALCULATION_TEST_RESOURCE_FILES})   
        get_filename_component(DESTINATION_FOLDER ${SOURCE_FILE} DIRECTORY) 
        list(APPEND LENSMETER_CALCULATION_TEST_RESOURCE_FOLDERS ${DESTINATION_FOLDER})              
    endforeach()

    list(APPEND LENSMETER_CALCULATION_TEST_BINARY_FILES ${LENSMETER_CALCULATION_TEST_RESOURCE_FILES})
endif()

add_executable(lensmeter_calculation_test ${LENSMETER_CALCULATION_TEST_BINARY_FILES})

target_link_libraries(lensmeter_calculation_test PUBLIC lensmeter_calculation)

list(REMOVE_DUPLICATES LENSMETER_CALCULATION_TEST_SOURCE_FOLDERS)
list(REMOVE_DUPLICATES LENSMETER_CALCULATION_TEST_HEADER_FOLDERS)
list(REMOVE_DUPLICATES LENSMETER_CALCULATION_TEST_RESOURCE_FOLDERS)

if(${LENSMETER_COPY_FILES})
    set(LENSMETER_CALCULATION_TEST_SOURCE_DIR ${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR})
else()
    set(LENSMETER_CALCULATION_TEST_SOURCE_DIR ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR})
endif()

target_include_directories(lensmeter_calculation_test PUBLIC "${LENSMETER_CALCULATION_TEST_SOURCE_DIR}/include")

add_compile_definitions(LENSMETER_CALCULATION_TEST_EXPORT)

foreach(LENSMETER_CALCULATION_TEST_SOURCE_FOLDER ${LENSMETER_CALCULATION_TEST_SOURCE_FOLDERS})
    string(COMPARE EQUAL ${LENSMETER_CALCULATION_TEST_SOURCE_FOLDER} ${LENSMETER_CALCULATION_TEST_SOURCE_DIR} IS_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR)

    if(NOT ${IS_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR} OR NOT ${LENSMETER_COPY_FILES}) 
        file(GLOB LENSMETER_CALCULATION_TEST_FOLDER_FILES "${LENSMETER_CALCULATION_TEST_SOURCE_FOLDER}/*.cpp")
        list(LENGTH LENSMETER_CALCULATION_TEST_FOLDER_FILES LENSMETER_CALCULATION_TEST_FOLDER_FILES_COUNT)

        string(REPLACE "${LENSMETER_CALCULATION_TEST_SOURCE_DIR}/src" "" LENSMETER_CALCULATION_TEST_GROUPNAME ${LENSMETER_CALCULATION_TEST_SOURCE_FOLDER})

        if(NOT ${LENSMETER_CALCULATION_TEST_GROUPNAME} STREQUAL "")
            string(REPLACE "/" "\\" LENSMETER_CALCULATION_TEST_GROUPNAME ${LENSMETER_CALCULATION_TEST_GROUPNAME})
            source_group("Source Files\\${LENSMETER_CALCULATION_TEST_GROUPNAME}" FILES ${LENSMETER_CALCULATION_TEST_FOLDER_FILES})      
        endif()
    endif()
endforeach()

foreach(LENSMETER_CALCULATION_TEST_HEADER_FOLDER ${LENSMETER_CALCULATION_TEST_HEADER_FOLDERS})
    string(COMPARE EQUAL ${LENSMETER_CALCULATION_TEST_HEADER_FOLDER} ${LENSMETER_CALCULATION_TEST_SOURCE_DIR} IS_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR)

    if(NOT ${IS_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR} OR NOT ${LENSMETER_COPY_FILES}) 
        file(GLOB LENSMETER_CALCULATION_TEST_FOLDER_FILES "${LENSMETER_CALCULATION_TEST_HEADER_FOLDER}/*.hpp")
        list(LENGTH LENSMETER_CALCULATION_TEST_FOLDER_FILES LENSMETER_CALCULATION_TEST_FOLDER_FILES_COUNT)

        string(REPLACE "${LENSMETER_CALCULATION_TEST_SOURCE_DIR}/include" "" LENSMETER_CALCULATION_TEST_GROUPNAME ${LENSMETER_CALCULATION_TEST_HEADER_FOLDER})

        if(NOT ${LENSMETER_CALCULATION_TEST_GROUPNAME} STREQUAL "")
            string(REPLACE "/" "\\" LENSMETER_CALCULATION_TEST_GROUPNAME ${LENSMETER_CALCULATION_TEST_GROUPNAME})
            source_group("Header Files\\${LENSMETER_CALCULATION_TEST_GROUPNAME}" FILES ${LENSMETER_CALCULATION_TEST_FOLDER_FILES})
        endif()
    endif()
endforeach()

foreach(LENSMETER_CALCULATION_TEST_RESOURCE_FOLDER ${LENSMETER_CALCULATION_TEST_RESOURCE_FOLDERS})
    string(COMPARE EQUAL ${LENSMETER_CALCULATION_TEST_RESOURCE_FOLDER} ${LENSMETER_CALCULATION_TEST_SOURCE_DIR} IS_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR)

    if(NOT ${IS_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR} OR NOT ${LENSMETER_COPY_FILES}) 
        file(GLOB LENSMETER_CALCULATION_TEST_FOLDER_FILES "${LENSMETER_CALCULATION_TEST_RESOURCE_FOLDER}/*.*")
        list(LENGTH LENSMETER_CALCULATION_TEST_FOLDER_FILES LENSMETER_CALCULATION_TEST_FOLDER_FILES_COUNT)

        string(REPLACE "${LENSMETER_CALCULATION_TEST_SOURCE_DIR}/resources" "" LENSMETER_CALCULATION_TEST_GROUPNAME ${LENSMETER_CALCULATION_TEST_RESOURCE_FOLDER})

        if(NOT ${LENSMETER_CALCULATION_TEST_GROUPNAME} STREQUAL "")
            string(REPLACE "/" "\\" LENSMETER_CALCULATION_TEST_GROUPNAME ${LENSMETER_CALCULATION_TEST_GROUPNAME})
            source_group("Resources\\${LENSMETER_CALCULATION_TEST_GROUPNAME}" FILES ${LENSMETER_CALCULATION_TEST_FOLDER_FILES})
        endif()
    endif()
endforeach()
```

**lensmeter_calculation CMakeLists.txt (library)**

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.15)

set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 17)
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD_REQUIRED ON)

if(NOT DEFINED LENSMETRER_COPY_FILES)
    set(LENSMETER_COPY_FILES FALSE CACHE BOOL "Specify if you want to copy sources and headers to build directory and refer to these" FORCE)
endif()

file(GLOB_RECURSE LENSMETER_CALCULATION_HEADER_FILES "include/*.*")

file(GLOB_RECURSE LENSMETER_CALCULATION_SOURCE_FILES "src/*.cpp")

if(${LENSMETER_COPY_FILES})
    foreach(SOURCE_FILE ${LENSMETER_CALCULATION_SOURCE_FILES})  
        string(REPLACE ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR} ${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR} DESTINATION_FILE ${SOURCE_FILE})
        get_filename_component(DESTINATION_FOLDER ${DESTINATION_FILE} DIRECTORY)    
        list(APPEND LENSMETER_CALCULATION_SOURCE_FOLDERS ${DESTINATION_FOLDER})
        list(APPEND LENSMETER_CALCULATION_BINARY_FILES ${DESTINATION_FILE})
        file(COPY ${SOURCE_FILE} DESTINATION ${DESTINATION_FOLDER})
    endforeach()
else()
    foreach(SOURCE_FILE ${LENSMETER_CALCULATION_SOURCE_FILES})  
        get_filename_component(DESTINATION_FOLDER ${SOURCE_FILE} DIRECTORY) 
        list(APPEND LENSMETER_CALCULATION_SOURCE_FOLDERS ${DESTINATION_FOLDER})             
    endforeach()

    list(APPEND LENSMETER_CALCULATION_BINARY_FILES ${LENSMETER_CALCULATION_SOURCE_FILES})
endif()

if(${LENSMETER_COPY_FILES})
    foreach(SOURCE_FILE ${LENSMETER_CALCULATION_HEADER_FILES})  
        string(REPLACE ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR} ${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR} DESTINATION_FILE ${SOURCE_FILE})
        get_filename_component(DESTINATION_FOLDER ${DESTINATION_FILE} DIRECTORY)
        list(APPEND LENSMETER_CALCULATION_HEADER_FOLDERS ${DESTINATION_FOLDER})
        list(APPEND LENSMETER_CALCULATION_BINARY_FILES ${DESTINATION_FILE})
        file(COPY ${SOURCE_FILE} DESTINATION ${DESTINATION_FOLDER})
    endforeach()
else()
    foreach(SOURCE_FILE ${LENSMETER_CALCULATION_HEADER_FILES})  
        get_filename_component(DESTINATION_FOLDER ${SOURCE_FILE} DIRECTORY) 
        list(APPEND LENSMETER_CALCULATION_HEADER_FOLDERS ${DESTINATION_FOLDER})             
    endforeach()

    list(APPEND LENSMETER_CALCULATION_BINARY_FILES ${LENSMETER_CALCULATION_HEADER_FILES})
endif()

find_package(OpenCV 3.4.1 REQUIRED)

add_library(lensmeter_calculation SHARED ${LENSMETER_CALCULATION_BINARY_FILES})

list(REMOVE_DUPLICATES LENSMETER_CALCULATION_SOURCE_FOLDERS)
list(REMOVE_DUPLICATES LENSMETER_CALCULATION_HEADER_FOLDERS)

include_directories(${OpenCV_INCLUDE_DIRS})

target_link_libraries(lensmeter_calculation ${OpenCV_LIBS})

if(${LENSMETER_COPY_FILES})
    set(LENSMETER_CALCULATION_SOURCE_DIR ${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR})
else()
    set(LENSMETER_CALCULATION_SOURCE_DIR ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR})
endif()

target_include_directories(lensmeter_calculation PUBLIC "${LENSMETER_CALCULATION_SOURCE_DIR}/include")

add_compile_definitions(LENSMETER_CALCULATION_EXPORT)

foreach(LENSMETER_CALCULATION_SOURCE_FOLDER ${LENSMETER_CALCULATION_SOURCE_FOLDERS})
    string(COMPARE EQUAL ${LENSMETER_CALCULATION_SOURCE_FOLDER} ${LENSMETER_CALCULATION_SOURCE_DIR} IS_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR)

    if(NOT ${IS_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR} OR NOT ${LENSMETER_COPY_FILES}) 
        file(GLOB LENSMETER_CALCULATION_FOLDER_FILES "${LENSMETER_CALCULATION_SOURCE_FOLDER}/*.cpp")
        list(LENGTH LENSMETER_CALCULATION_FOLDER_FILES LENSMETER_CALCULATION_FOLDER_FILES_COUNT)

        string(REPLACE "${LENSMETER_CALCULATION_SOURCE_DIR}/src" "" LENSMETER_CALCULATION_GROUPNAME ${LENSMETER_CALCULATION_SOURCE_FOLDER})

        message("Source group name to add -> ${LENSMETER_CALCULATION_GROUPNAME}")

        if(NOT ${LENSMETER_CALCULATION_GROUPNAME} STREQUAL "")
            string(REPLACE "/" "\\" LENSMETER_CALCULATION_GROUPNAME ${LENSMETER_CALCULATION_GROUPNAME})
            source_group("Source Files\\${LENSMETER_CALCULATION_GROUPNAME}" FILES ${LENSMETER_CALCULATION_FOLDER_FILES})        
            message("Header group name added -> ${LENSMETER_CALCULATION_GROUPNAME}")
        endif()
    endif()
endforeach()

foreach(LENSMETER_CALCULATION_HEADER_FOLDER ${LENSMETER_CALCULATION_HEADER_FOLDERS})
    string(COMPARE EQUAL ${LENSMETER_CALCULATION_HEADER_FOLDER} ${LENSMETER_CALCULATION_SOURCE_DIR} IS_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR)

    if(NOT ${IS_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR} OR NOT ${LENSMETER_COPY_FILES}) 
        file(GLOB LENSMETER_CALCULATION_FOLDER_FILES "${LENSMETER_CALCULATION_HEADER_FOLDER}/*.*")
        list(LENGTH LENSMETER_CALCULATION_FOLDER_FILES LENSMETER_CALCULATION_FOLDER_FILES_COUNT)

        string(REPLACE "${LENSMETER_CALCULATION_SOURCE_DIR}/include" "" LENSMETER_CALCULATION_GROUPNAME ${LENSMETER_CALCULATION_HEADER_FOLDER})

        message("Header group name to add -> ${LENSMETER_CALCULATION_GROUPNAME}")

        if(NOT ${LENSMETER_CALCULATION_GROUPNAME} STREQUAL "")
            string(REPLACE "/" "\\" LENSMETER_CALCULATION_GROUPNAME ${LENSMETER_CALCULATION_GROUPNAME})
            source_group("Header Files\\${LENSMETER_CALCULATION_GROUPNAME}" FILES ${LENSMETER_CALCULATION_FOLDER_FILES})
            message("Header group name added -> ${LENSMETER_CALCULATION_GROUPNAME}")
        endif() 
    endif()
endforeach()
```

---

**UPDATE 1:**

Below the tree view of my solution

**1. Principal CMakeLists.txt file**

This `CMakeLists.txt` contains all `add_subdirectory()` for all modules.

```
...
add_subdirectory("modules\\lensmeter_calculation")
add_subdirectory("modules\\lensmeter_camera")
add_subdirectory("modules\\lensmeter_motion")
add_subdirectory("modules\\lensmeter_spectrometer")
...
```

**2. Module folder**

I added another `CMakeLists.txt` file that contains main module and the test project associated for comodity (it's not necessary but it's more clearly for me).

```
...
add_subdirectory("lensmeter_calculation")
add_subdirectory("lensmeter_calculation_test")
...
```

Then i have the specific CMakeLists.txt for each library/executable showed in the original post

Comment: In your `lensmeter_calculation_test/CMakeLists.txt` file, the library `lensmeter_calculation` is not defined, so the `target_link_libraries()` call doesn't know where to find it. Do you have a top-level CMake file that calls these two CMake files, via `add_subdirectory()`? If not, I would consider adding this, so that the `lensmeter_calculation` target defined in the one CMake file can be found and used by the other CMake file.

Comment: @squareskittles Yes of course, i have a top CMakeLists.txt that contains ´lensmeter_calculation´ and ´lensmeter_calculation_test´. The problem is that Visual Studio recognize my reference project but not the build path that contains .lib file

Comment: Can you please add the code showing this top-level file to your question post? The ordering of your `add_subdirectory()` calls matters.

Comment: @squareskittles updated just now